# redux form returns nothing when calling submit function in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a simple redux form with react native,but when I call submit function it returns an empty array?

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Field,reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Text,Input } from 'react-native-elements';
import { View,Button } from 'react-native';
import {Icon,CheckBox} from 'react-native-elements';
 const renderField=({label,keyboardType,name,icon,iconType}) => {
    return(
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <Input keyboardType={keyboardType} placeholder={label} inputContainerStyle={{borderWidth:2,borderColor:'lightgrey',borderRadius:20}} inputStyle={{color:'grey'}} leftIcon={<Icon size={25} type={iconType} name={icon} color="grey" />} errorStyle={{fontSize:15}} errorMessage="error" />
            </View>
    )
}
 const checkBoxField=({label,keyboardType,name}) => {
    return(
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <Text>{label}</Text>
                <CheckBox  title='Male' checkedIcon='dot-circle-o' uncheckedIcon='circle-o' checked={true} containerStyle={{backgroundColor:'transparent',marginBottom:10}} />      
            </View>
    )
}

const submit=values=>{
    console.log(values)
}
const RegisterForm=props => {
    const {handleSubmit}=props;
    return(
            <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',margin:20,justifyContent:'flex-start',alignItems:'center'}}>

                <Field label="Username" component={renderField} name="username" icon="user" iconType="font-awesome" />
                <Field label="Email" component={renderField} name="email" icon="email" iconType="zocial" />
                <Field label="Gender" component={checkBoxField} name="gender" />
                <Button title='SUBMIT' onPress={handleSubmit(submit)} />

            </View>
    )
}
const Register=reduxForm({
    form:'register',

})(RegisterForm);
export default Register;
```

In the above code when clicking on the submit button it will call submit function with parameters,but nothing will printed in console.what the issue is here?

Comment: I missed the change text part, i'll delete my answer.

Comment: wow that looks right, i dont know what can be causing that. instead of logging `values` try logging a string, to see if it gets into that function.

Comment: @Pranab Did you figure out?

Answer (score 0):

When you press the submit button you are calling props.handleSubmit() with your submit function, but the onPress() handler from the Button component does not accept any arguments.

So your submit() function never actually gets called.